# how to make two bars in the same fig Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to make two bars in the same fig in matlab. Now, I have two separate bar charts, what I want to do is combining them in one chart but with different colors (eg red and blue) to differentiate between the two barcharts.
This is the two barcharts appearing:[image: bar1][image: bar2]

what I want to do is something like this:
[image: wanted]

Below is the code I'm using so if anyone could please help me.

```
load('x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms.mat');
uu=unique(n);
nn=histc(n, uu);
h=figure; bar(uu,nn/numel(n));
print(h, '-dpdf', 'x1000');
saveas(h,'x1000','fig');

load('k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms.mat');
uu=unique(n);
nn=histc(n, uu);
h=figure; bar(uu,nn/numel(n));
print(h, '-dpdf', 'k1000');
saveas(h,'k1000','fig');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the examples in `bar()` and specifically about [bar styles](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthxce9):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the line "hold on" before your code for the second bar graph and "hold off" after.

```
> load('x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms.mat');
   uu=unique(n);
   nn=histc(n, uu);
   h=figure; bar(uu,nn/numel(n));
   print(h, '-dpdf', 'x1000');
   saveas(h,'x1000','fig');

   load('k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms.mat');
   uu=unique(n);
   hold on;
   nn=histc(n, uu);
   h=figure; bar(uu,nn/numel(n));
   print(h, '-dpdf', 'k1000');
   saveas(h,'k1000','fig');
   hold off;
```

Comment: its working now but the bars are on top of each other, how to separate them with distance?

Comment: @user1460166 Sorry for the late response, if you are still trying to get the appearance of your second bar chart try adjusting the width of your bars. bar(...,'width'). I hope that is helpful.