# Separate bars in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to separate the two graph bars shown in the below figure
this is the code I'm using:[image: res]

```
bar(uu,nn/numel(n));
hold on
bar(uu1,nn1/numel(n1),'r');
hold off
```

, but I want them to be like this:[image]

Update:
I'm using the below code suggested by Shai but the fig. is now not correct, as there is white space in the beginning and the values of the y axis are not correct
:
[image]

```
bar(uu-.5, nn/numel(nn), .5);hold all;bar(uu1, nn1/numel(nn1),.5,'r');
hleg = legend('Kinect','Xtion','Location','NorthEast');
```

Comment: I suggest using [distributionPlot](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661) from the File Exchange for plotting/comparing multiple distributions.

Comment: how `uu` and `uu1` are related?

Comment: @Shai the xaxis represent the values and y-axis representing the percentage. DO you know how to separate them?

Comment: if `uu` was identical to `uu1` then you could simply use `bar( uu, [nn(:)/numel(n) , nn1(:)/numel(n1)] );legend({'a','b'});`

Comment: @Shai  nope they are not :(

Comment: do you make `nn` abd `nn1` using `hist` command?

Comment: @Shai yes i am using hist command

Comment: Can you use the same bins for both `hist` commands?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16312749/how-to-make-two-bars-in-the-same-fig-matlab

Comment: @Shai this is my question also :) and it worked but the result is the one I'm describing here. In the other question the two bars was plotted but also on top of each other :(

Comment: try: `bar(uu-.5, nn1/numel(nn1), .5);hold all;bar(uu1, nn1/numel(nn1),.5);`

Comment: @Shai I've used your proposed solution and updated my question. I don't know why the y-axis value is not correct (it represent the percentage out of 1) but I its not appearing too small and not correct. Also why there is a white space in the beginning of the x-axis?

Comment: my bad, I divided by `numel(nn)` instead of `numel(n)` (same for `nn1`). - this should fix your y-axis.

Comment: @Shai Thanks (Y) will you post an answer to mark it as solved?

Comment: ok - I posted it as an answer. glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround can be shifting a bit the `y` values of the sequences:

```
bar(uu-.25, nn/numel(n), .5);
hold all;
bar(uu1 + .25, nn1/numel(n1),.5);
legend({'a','b'});
```