# How to overlay histograms in matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart

I have multiple histograms that I would like to overlay on top of each other but I don't know how to do it. I found the code below but I don't know how to modify it to run on a loop instead of just two histograms.

```
data1 = randn(100,1);       % data of one size
data2 = randn(25, 1);       % data of another size!

myBins = linspace(-3,3,10); % pick my own bin locations

% Hists will be the same size because we set the bin locations:
y1 = hist(data1, myBins);   
y2 = hist(data2, myBins);

% plot the results:
figure(3);
bar(myBins, [y1;y2]');
title('Mixed size result');
```

[image]

or what is a better way of comparing histograms if they are more than 10 or 20.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Separate bars in matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16313392/separate-bars-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following, although it's not the only way:

```
data = cell(1, N);
y = cell(1, N);
yBar = zeros(N, 10);
for i=1:N
    data{1, i} = randn(10*round(rand(1,1)), 1);
    y{1, i} = hist(data{1, i}, myBins);
    yBar(i, :) = y{1, i};
end
yBar = yBar';
figure(3);
bar(myBins, yBar);
title('Mixed size result');
```

Using the y cell is not obligatory of course, I left it there to actually show what's happening.

Comment: in your code, yBar always has the same length (10) but what should I do if that's not the case. mine changes every time...

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very general. Firstly I do not understand why you insist on a for loop.

Personally I don't like the included bar plot. It quickly gets messy (especially since the bars are not at the "original" location)

If you got a lot of histograms I would consider a [stairstep](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) plot as it doesn't fill the plot area so much. Or you could come up with your own - eg using transparent patches.

If it get's lots of curves there are many ways to visualize them google for "multivariate visualization" and be amazed. One of the most amusing ways would be [Chernoff faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_face).

Comment: I simply have speed of bunch of bacteria moving over time. and at each time there is a histogram of the speed. we watch about 40 times. so there are 40 histograms of speed change. the histograms are pretty much bell curves, shifting to one side over time. What do you think is the correct way of showing this?

Comment: if it's approximately bell curves I would start by plotting the mean and standard deviation. Mabe along the lines of this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27485

Answer (score 2):

it's much easier now:

```
histogram(data1, myBins);
hold on;   
histogram(data2, myBins);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this. It's simple and does not require `for` loops:

```
bar([y1.' y2.'],'stacked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that was useful to me:

[image]

I'm plotting a histogram for each column of the matrix `ao`.

The code was:

```
    for i = 1:size(ao,2)
        [h, y] = hist(ao(:,i), linspace(-5,10,100));
        h = i + (0.95./max(h(:))) .* h;
        barh(y, h, 'BarWidth', 1, 'BaseValue', i, 'LineStyle', 'none');
        hold on;
    end
    grid;
```

Note that just changing `barh` to `bar` will give the same thing but going up-down instead of left-right (i.e. the figure rotated by 90° anti-clockwise).

Comment: I have never seen one like that, and find it very hard to understand.